# juniper-security answer

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, security, juniper-srx

[edit firewall filter test ]

```
term 1 {
  from {
    source-address {
      10.0.0.0/8;
    }
  }
  then {
    log;
    next term;
  }
}
term 2 {
  then {
    reject ;
  }
}
```

How is traffic, sourced from 10.0.0.0/8, treated by the firewall filter shown in the exhibit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Term 1 logs all traffic from 10/8, `next term` means evaluation of firewall filter rules continues. Term 2 rejects *all* traffic. So traffic gets rejected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply